# How to design an event listener app to only process events once and also be HA and scalable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, scaling, high-availability, system-design

I have a situation where I have a NodeJs app that runs as an event listener. This NodeJs app listens for external events outside of my application through websocket.

I need each of the events coming in to only be processed once by my Nodejs app.

However, it's also crucial to ensure that this particular NodeJs app instance can auto-scale up/down when needed and is highly available so that it wouldn't be a bottleneck.

Usually, when it comes to scaling and HA, the first thing that come to my mind is to run a few of instances of it with a load balancer, or run multiple containers on something like ECS. Doing so would introduce multiple instances of the Nodejs app and would also mean each of the same events from the websocket will get processed more than once by all the instances/containers which received it.

What would be a good solution and design to tackle such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the situation here but I think what you are saying is that you have a socket server that emit to other services, however that a single instance, even with dedicated resources is subject to bottlenecks.

Assuming what I have said is in-line with the question what you probably want to look at (not sure if you using socket.io or not) is the redis socket.io package. This will essentially use redis to store the sockets so you can cluster your socket server and not have it sending duplicates or missed users.

To your question about scale, you for sure would want to use containers for this, we actually use digitalocean 'apps' as an easy way to deploy our containers without having to manage Kuberneties and docker images, only downside right now is no auto scale, however scaling out is just a click of a button and with alerts setup we know when to scale up or down.

With this setup, we have our socket server running with managed redis server, when we need more socket server we just tick it up and we have more throughput.

Comment: My apologies if I haven't been clear in my question. What I meant is I have a nodejs app that listens for external websocket events from outside of my application. If I'm not wrong, using a redis would mean to publish events. In my case, I'm trying to listen for events. But I only want each event to be processed only once. Yet, I want to have scalability and HA for this particular listener application. What I have in mind for HA and scalability is to have multiple instances of that application which would then mean each same event being processed multiple times.

Comment: So redis would work in this situation or other redis adapters for like cluster etc. Again, not sure if you are using socket.io but they have docs on their site, but the concept is the same, you need a way to scale you socket servers while maintains the correct emits, because each client connecting to other servers gets a unique socket.id, the adapters keep track of that and and emit on server one will trigger it on server 2, 3, 4 etc. so you emit to channel A will send to all channel A sockets across your cluster

Comment: Does this mean the redis cluster will be the one listening for the external websocket events and then passes it on to the clients connected to it?

Comment: No, redis is just the one storing the socket information, the socket.io redis adapter essentially allows you to run 'emits' in your code while in a clustered setup, take care of sending out the correct data, regardless of what socket server they were connected to. Check out the docs, they go into more detail and probably doing a better job then I in these little boxes :D https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/

Comment: I see. Thanks. In my case, I don’t really have to emit events through the socket. The events are emitted from an external source outside my application. Think of a third-party source. I’m more concern with receiving the events within my application. I want the part within my application that receives the events from the socket to be HA. So I’m not sure if the redis adapter could help since it’s meant for emitting events instead of receiving events?

Answer (score 0):

I am running through the same design challenge. The only viable solution I can think of is to create HA mode manually by running 2 or more different Nodejs applications. One of them needs to be the leader, and the others need to be aware of that. You can expose an endpoint that tells you whether a node is a leader or not. Only the leader will process messages from the websocket server. Other nodes will read and dismiss. When the leader goes down, the other node(s) will know since they should be constantly polling whether the leader is still the leader.

Another solution would be to have all nodes connect to the websocket server and push messages to a redis cluster. You can have another application (or thread in the same application) that is reading from redis and would process the messages. You want to avoid publishing duplicate messages to redis. Either create a delay before processing a new message and popping it. Wait until the others write the same data and process once. Or write to a different cluster or key where data isn't popped or not read at all, rather expires automatically. The nodejs listener application will check redis if the message exists before pushing. You can hash your messages to obtain unique redis keys.